# Retrieving multiple Organisations from a single logon - through API

Tags: xero-api

On the Xero website, i can click on "My Xero" and it will return a list of organisations that i have created. Is it possible to return this list of organisations through the API functionality

Currently im logging in (through oauth) and then i only have access to that one organisation that the client selected. but im looking for a list of organisations registered to the xero profile

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not - the OAuth 1.0a process results in an access token that is specific to the Xero organisation, rather than the Xero user, so it's not feasible to have an endpoint that lists organisations for a user.

Comment: Thank you Rusty, Do you know if any other Auth Process would give me the result i require?

Comment: No, the endpoint doesn't exist; OAuth 1.0a is the only auth process available at the moment.